# Creating a WWAN profile in NMCLI, or alternate way of connecting to 3G via CLI?

Tags: command-line, server, network-manager, 3g, nmcli

I need to connect to the internet via a TP-Link MA260. After spending hours with usb_modeswitch and other tools, I finally got the device to be recognised as a modem and have the interface `wwan0`.

I've tried various commands and configs with `wvdial`, but, I just can't seem to get it to connect.

After reading up many guides, I heard about Network Manager's CLI, so, I installed network manager on to Ubuntu Server.

When I perform `nmcli nm` it shows

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         disabled
```

I then spent so long looking around the internet, and I stumbled upon this question: [How to enable/disable mobile broadband from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137815/how-to-enable-disable-mobile-broadband-from-terminal), which got me a little further, however, all answers refer to `nmcli -t con up id "bla"`.

No matter what I try, I can't work out how to create `"bla"`, or how I should define the 3G settings, and even when I do find it, I'm not sure what to write.

I found a guide that says that I have to type `nmcli con xx`, but, edit or add don't seem like valid options and I am stuck.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to connect?

Comment: Have you tried using ModemManager? From their website: "ModemManager is a DBus-activated daemon which controls mobile broadband (2G/3G/4G) devices and connections". It works together with NetworkManager.